# Which tools and technologies are used to build android apps like instagram, twitter clients?

Tags: android, cordova, appcelerator-mobile

Just want to know which tools and technologies are used to build popular android app like instagram app, facebook app, twitter clients etc? do they use framework like phoneGap or appcelerator or they write native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appcelerator is not a webview wrapper like phone gap. It complies down to use native code to generate its app.

I would assume that most large scale companies would invest in having a native app built for all of there solutions.

If this is to judge what you should use the best approach is not to copy what others do but to see what is required for your application and what best suites your skill set

Answer (score -2):

Twitter and Facebook apps are mostly in HTML5. The Instagram app uses HTML5 web views at some points like displaying streams. I guess the reason for this is that they have to support multiple platforms while keeping the user experience for the streams consistent.

PhoneGap is a wrapper around Android and iPhone web views for the most part. I doubt that FB/Twitter uses it though.

*Edit*
Seems like was wrong about Appcelerator.